# Why I'm getting an unresolved depandency error in my AEM OSGI bundle?

Tags: java, maven-2, aem-6, aem-core-wcm-components

My OSGI bundle will not start if I use the AEM wcm core components (to be specific the Image component) in my java code:

```
package be.ovl.aem.services.models.components.content.enhancedimage.impl;

import be.ovl.aem.services.models.components.content.enhancedimage.EnhancedImage;

**import com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.models.Image;**
import lombok.Data;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Via;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.Self;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.injectorspecific.ValueMapValue;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.via.ResourceSuperType;


@Data
@Model(
        adaptables = Resource.class,
        adapters = EnhancedImage.class,
        resourceType = "ovl/components/content/enhanced-image"
)
public class EnhancedImageImpl implements EnhancedImage {
    
    @ValueMapValue
    String imageText;
    
    @ValueMapValue
    String imageCopyright;

    @Self
    @Via(type = ResourceSuperType.class)
    private Image image;

    public String getImageText() {
        return imageText;
    }

    public void setImageText(String imageText) {
        this.imageText = imageText;
    }

    public String getImageCopyright() {
        return imageCopyright;
    }

    public void setImageCopyright(String imageCopyright) {
        this.imageCopyright = imageCopyright;
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

In the Adobe Experience Manager Web Console Bundles, I see this:

=> com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.models,version=[11.1,12) -- Cannot be resolved

I'm using Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) 6.3.1.

If I change the uber-jar version in the POM from 6.3.1 to 6.3.1.2, then it resolves but I get another unresolved depandency in my bundle. The POM:

```
<!-- AEM public API -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
     <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
     <version>6.3.1.2</version>
     <classifier>apis</classifier>
     <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

And this is the unresolved depandency:

=> org.apache.sling.xss,version=[2.0,3) -- Cannot be resolved

It seems like the chicken and the egg problem... Can someone help me please?